# correlation calculation on hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, statistics, correlation

If I want to calculate correlation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) of large volume of data on grid and also large number of dimensions (on which dimension I want to calculate correlation to outcomes), I am wondering if there are any existing or smarter way to the implementation on Hadoop grid?

Pig/Java/Python implementations are preferred. :)

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Why are you using Pearsons Correleation Coefficient? Suggest you use Mutual Information, it's much more general. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence#Other_measures_of_dependence_among_random_variables  As for your question, it's a little vague to be able to provide an implementation.  You need to be more specific as to what form your data is in.

Comment: I think Mutual Information could not give a qualitative measure like confidence interval to see how good/bad the match is? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes and no.  It depends how your perform your probability estimation.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you show me how to use MI together with confidence interval? Thanks.

Comment: Very simply; when you estimate your probabilities, you can define a confidence interval (which will depend on your sample size and the prior), this can then induce a confidence interval on your MI.